# pthread_join() mixing threads outputs

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I studied about pthread_join() I get to know that it run thread until thread processing is done, But in my case it is not working like this, I've to create 4 threads using 2 functions, I was expecting output as fun1,fun2,fun1 and fun2 again, because I'm calling threads in this sequence. Here is my code to describe my question more clearly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *thread1()
{
int c=0;
while(c++ < 10)
printf("%i : Hello!!\n",c);
}
void *thread2()
{
int c=0;
while(c++ < 10)
printf("%i : How Are You!!\n",c);
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[], char *env[] )
{
pthread_t tid1,tid2,tid3,tid4;
pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
pthread_create(&tid3,NULL,thread1,NULL);
pthread_create(&tid4,NULL,thread2,NULL);
pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
pthread_join(tid3,NULL);
pthread_join(tid4,NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Output variate every time, give different output every time, I don't understand whats happening.
**Output :**

```
1 : Hello!!
2 : Hello!!
3 : Hello!!
4 : Hello!!
5 : Hello!!
6 : Hello!!
7 : Hello!!
1 : How Are You!!
1 : How Are You!!
2 : How Are You!!
3 : How Are You!!
4 : How Are You!!
8 : Hello!!
9 : Hello!!
10 : Hello!!
2 : How Are You!!
3 : How Are You!!
4 : How Are You!!
5 : How Are You!!
6 : How Are You!!
7 : How Are You!!
8 : How Are You!!
9 : How Are You!!
10 : How Are You!!
5 : How Are You!!
6 : How Are You!!
7 : How Are You!!
8 : How Are You!!
9 : How Are You!!
10 : How Are You!!
1 : Hello!!
2 : Hello!!
3 : Hello!!
4 : Hello!!
5 : Hello!!
6 : Hello!!
7 : Hello!!
8 : Hello!!
9 : Hello!!
10 : Hello!!
```

what I was expecting

```
1 : Hello!!
2 : Hello!!
3 : Hello!!
4 : Hello!!
5 : Hello!!
6 : Hello!!
7 : Hello!!
8 : Hello!!
9 : Hello!!
10 : Hello!!
1 : How Are You!!
2 : How Are You!!
3 : How Are You!!
4 : How Are You!!
5 : How Are You!!
6 : How Are You!!
7 : How Are You!!
8 : How Are You!!
9 : How Are You!!
10 : How Are You!!
1 : Hello!!
2 : Hello!!
3 : Hello!!
4 : Hello!!
5 : Hello!!
6 : Hello!!
7 : Hello!!
8 : Hello!!
9 : Hello!!
10 : Hello!!
1 : How Are You!!
2 : How Are You!!
3 : How Are You!!
4 : How Are You!!
5 : How Are You!!
6 : How Are You!!
7 : How Are You!!
8 : How Are You!!
9 : How Are You!!
10 : How Are You!!
```

Can anyone describe what's happening here ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, `pthread_join(t, NULL)` does not do anything to thread `t`.  It does not "run thread until thread processing is done," it does not notify the thread that you are trying join it.  All it does is _wait_ for the thread to finish its work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I was expecting output as fun1,fun2,fun1 and fun2 again, because I'm calling threads in this sequence.*

Threads aren't sequenced - they run independently.  If you want the different threads to be synchronized or sequenced in any way, you have to code that yourself using things like mutexes, semaphores, condition variables, or some other explicit synchronization method.

You can't expect *any* particular execution order between separate threads without such explicit synchronization.

Comment: So pthread_join(); is only responsible to execute a thread, not for it's termination ?

Comment: @MohammadTayyab `pthread_join()` doesn't execute a thread - it merely stops the thread that calls `pthread_join()` wait until the thread that matches the thread ID passed to `pthread_join()` finishes executing.  If that thread runs for a long time, the `pthread_join()` call will wait for a long time.  If the matching thread is already finished executing, `pthread_join()` will return immediately.

Comment: Ok! @Andrew Henle So my output is totally normal. There is nothing wrong ? Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Because threads run in a parallel manner they run independently of each other. If you want them to be in a sequence using this way:

```
    pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid3,NULL,thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid3,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid4,NULL,thread2,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid4,NULL);
```

Now when we have created thread `t1` it will execute and `pthread_join()` will wait for finishing its execution. after thread `t1` will finish its execution now we are creating another thread `t2` and now it will run.
So in this way we can get output in a sequence.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it's wasteful to use threads at all. The same effect could be achieved by calling the thread function(s) directly (given that they don't call pthread_exit()).

Comment: Yeah this defeats the entire purpose of multithreading. If you ever find yourself wanting a series of things to be executed *in a particular order*, using separate threads for those things is generally not a good solution